# Future tense in reported questions

Tags: future, indirect-speech

Context: Boyfriend often stays out late. Girlfriend wants to say that she doesn't worry about this.

> 1. Incorrect: "I don't usually ask him when he comes home"
> 2. Correct: "I don't usually ask him when he will come home"

'*When he will come home*' is the thing that is being asked about.

I'm having trouble explaining to my girlfriend why it is acceptable to use the future tense here. She learnt in a textbook not to use the future tense in some similar sentences (cf "I'll call you when I get home" vs "I'll call you when I **will** get home")

Can we describe (2) as a kind of reported question? What differentiates the first example from the second?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: As he is leaving, the question (if it were asked) would be "When will you come home?"

Comment: What else is relevant from the textbook that you could share?

Comment: I think 1 contains an indirect question (_when he comes home_) corresponding to a direct question, as in 1a. _I don't usually ask him, "When do you come home?"_. Do you find 1a incorrect? If not, why do you think 1 is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, *when he comes home* would naturally be interpreted as an adjunct denoting time. Something akin to:

*When he comes home, I don't usually ask him where he's been.*

*I don't usually ask him questions when he comes home.*

*I don't usually ask him ___ when he comes home*

The last one would have the question asked understood through context so the gap would be no problem and *when he comes home* would still be interpreted as denoting the time of the asking.

However, since interrogative content clauses and adjuncts headed by prepositions *when and where* have the same form, in a different context, we might still interpret your first sentence as *I don't usually ask him the question, "When do you come home?"*.

If we put a modal auxiliary verb in the clause governed by *when* it becomes clear that it is an interrogative, not a declarative, clause. This is because we use the futurate, the present tense pointing to future time, in subordinate clauses in adjuncts denoting time or order.

*I wonder [when he might come home].*      interrogative

*I asked him [when he might be home].*       interrogative

*I might ask him [when [he comes home tonight]].*  declarative

Note that only the declarative one can be fronted.

*When he comes home tonight, I might ask him.*

Comment: The OP clearly states "_When he will come home_ is the thing that is being asked about." So in the OP's example, _when he will come home_ is complement of the verb _ask_, not an adjunct. Why are you even mentioning the adjunct use, then?

Comment: OP asked how to explain his use of the "future tense" in the correct sentence to his girlfriend who read in a textbook that the "future tense" is not to be used in sentences similar to this. I was pointing out the difference between when it's acceptable, and when it isn't. The adjunct use is important in differentiating the first sentence from the second, hence answering OP's question.

Comment: Okay. In a context where _when he will come home_ is not an adjunct but a complement in 1, do you think 1 is incorrect?

Comment: I believe that would make 1 the same as 2 in OP’s post where _when he will come home_  is an interrogative content clause in _I don’t usually ask him when he will come home_ . No issues there. Also, I don’t believe there’s a situation under which _when he will come home_ would be considered an adjunct.

Comment: Since you didn't point out that 1 is not incorrect, I thought you agreed with OP that 1 was incorrect.

Comment: I did point out the two separate interpretations of OP's sentence number one in my answer. I also thought I made clear that OP's sentence number two permitted only one interpretation, the one desired in this context. There's nothing **grammatically** incorrect about OP's sentence number one.